# Why is there 2 Eucalyptus command sets?

Tags: eucalyptus

Does anyone know why there is two command sets for working with EE Cloud - their syntaxes are:

euca-command-subcommand
      and
   euform-command-subcommand ?

The have partially the same commands, so I suppose there are different use cases for them ?

Thank you
 Rainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

euca-* commands generally relate to the EC2 service.

There are other prefixes for other AWS (compatible) services:

- euare-*   : identity and access management
- euform-*  : cloudformation
- eulb-*    : elastic load balancing
- euscale-* : auto scaling
- euwatch-* : cloudwatch

Euca2ools documentation:

http://docs.hpcloud.com/eucalyptus/4.2.2/#euca2ools-guide/index.html